# Flowchart with overlapping of the rows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

how to change the code so it don't overlap like in the picture
if its possible that the first if go the second Output with out overlap other rows.
Secondly is there another possibility to make new line inside the if section.

thank you for your support.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.2cm, auto]
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
    \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    
    % Place nodes
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    
    \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input: f(), a, b, $\varepsilon$};
    
    \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {c=(a+b)/2};
    
    \node (if1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-1.5cm] {if: f(a)*f(b)$>$0};
    
    
    %   \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
    \node (dec1) [decision, below of=if1, yshift=-4cm] {While: f(c) $\not=$ 0 \& $|$f(b) - f(a)$|$ $> \delta$};
    
    \node (pro1a) [process, below of=dec1, yshift=-3cm] {c=(a+b)/2};
    
    \node (dec2) [decision, below of=pro1a,yshift=-1.75cm] {if: f(a)*f(c) $<$ 0};
    
    \node (pro2) [process, left of=dec2, xshift=-3cm] {b=c};
    
    \node (pro3) [process, below of=dec2, yshift=-1.5cm] {a=c};
    
    \node (out1) [io, below of=pro3] {Output: H, V, T};
    \node (out2) [io, left of=out1,xshift=-4.5cm] {Output: H, V, T};
    \node (pro4) [process, below of=out1] {Plot:H on T and V on T};
    \node (stop) [startstop, below of=pro4] {Stop};
    
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
    \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
    \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (if1);
    \draw [arrow] (if1) -- node {False} (dec1);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node {True} (pro1a);
    \draw [arrow] (pro1a) -- (dec2);
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node {False}(pro3);
    
    %\draw [arrow] (if1)  -- ++(-5.5,-0) -- ++(-1.5,0) |- node[below right] {True} (out2)
    \draw [arrow] (if1) -| node [above right] {True} (out2);
    \draw [arrow] (pro2) |- (dec1);
    \draw [arrow] (pro3)  -- ++(-3.5,-0) -- ++(-2.5,0) |-  (dec1);
    
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node {True} (pro2);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- ++(2.5,-0) -- ++(3,0) |- node[right] {False} (out1);
    \draw [arrow] (out1) -- (pro4);
    \draw [arrow] (out2) |- (stop);
    \draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (stop);
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: overlapping]

Additional Question: How to tell LaTex to draw between two process like the example in the picture

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and contains the minimal code that is need to reproduce the problem you have. Also, please clarify what you want to achieve: Do you mean that the arrow on the left should not overlap nodes? Do you mean that the text in the green diamond in the center, which is quite long, should break over two lines? Please fix and advise.

Comment: I suppose you have taken the node styles from here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)%E2%80%94Creating_Flowcharts.

Comment: yeah I have take it from there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that you may liked :-)

[image]

- Above flowchart is written almost from scratch.
- Instead of obsolete `\tikzstyle`  nodes styles are defined as options of `tikzpicture`.
- However, if you prefer to have defined them in document preamble, then you can move in `\tikset{<styles definitions>}` placed in preamble
- Flowchart code become more concise and clear, if in position of main branch is employed Ti*k*Z library `chains` with its macro `join`
- Consistent placement of nodes in chain as well other nodes gives use of Ti*k*Z library `positioning` which syntax `...=of <node name>` (instead of obsolete `... of = <node name>` used in your MWE) define distances between nodes borders. By this is prevented their eventual overlaps.
- I took a some liberty and in some nodes write text in several lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
     base/.style = {draw, fill=#1,
                    minimum width=34mm, minimum height=7mm, align=left,
                    font=\ttfamily},
startstop/.style = {base=red!30, rounded corners},
  process/.style = {base=orange!30},
       io/.style = {base=blue!30,
                    trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
 decision/.style = {base=green!30, diamond, aspect=1.5},
      arr/.style = {semithick,-latex}
                        ]
% nodes in chain
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node   [startstop] {Start};                         % name: A-1
\node   [io]        {Input:\\ f(), a, b, $\varepsilon$};
\node   [process]   {c=(a+b)/2};
\node   [decision]  {if:\\ f(a)*f(b)$>$0};           % A-4
 \node  [decision]  {While:\\                        % A-5
                    f(c) $\not=$ 0 \& \\ 
                    $|$f(b) - f(a)$|$ $> \delta$};
\node   [process]   {c=(a+b)/2};
\node   [decision]  {if:\\ f(a)*f(c)\textless 0};    % A-7
\node   [process]   {a=c};

\node   [io, suppress join] 
                    {Output: H, V, T};
\node   [process]   {Plot:\\ H on T and V on T};
\node   [startstop] {Stop};
    \end{scope}
\node   (a) [process, left=of A-7]  {b=c};
\node   (b) [io, left=of A-9]       {Output: H, V, T};
%
\path   (A-4) edge["False"] (A-5) 
        (A-5) edge["True"]  (A-6)
        (A-7) edge["False"] (A-8)
        (A-7) edge["True"]  (a) 
        ;
\draw[arr] (A-5.east) to["false"] ++ (2,0) |- (A-9);
\draw[arr] (a) |- (A-5);
\draw[arr] (A-8) -| ([shift={(-1em,-0)}] a.west) % <---
                 |- (A-5);
\draw[arr] (A-4) -| node[pos=0.1, above] {True}
            ([shift={(-2em,-2em)}] a.south west) % <---
                 |- (b);
\draw[arr] (b)   |- (A-10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
The another answer of @Qrrbrbirlbel provide an intriguing idea, so here is a test its adaption to above proposition. At this is in comparison to original proposition changed the following:

- removed `scope` for put nodes in chain
- macro `join` (which here doesn't work) is replaced with `\foreach` loop
- consider @Qrrbrbirlbel idea about drawing `decision` nodes
- used `-|-` path coordinated where is appropriate (sensible)
- labels of decision result are written as nodes options
- nodes names are renamed (that can be easy distingues from names in the original answer)
- added is additional loop arrow on the right (despite that it -- to my opinion -- is logical wrong)

Resulted image is more compact, not very different code which can be easy to understand:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
        arrows.meta,      % arrow tips
        chains,           % start chain, on chain
        ext.paths.ortho,  % -|- and |-| path operations
        positioning,      % ...=of <node>
        shapes.geometric  % for diamond at "if" node
                }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
   node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
      arr/.style = {semithick,-Stealth},
     base/.style = {draw=#1, semithick, fill=#1!25,
                    text width=32mm, minimum height=7mm, align=center,
                    font=\ttfamily,
                    on chain=A
                    },
       be/.style = {% BeginEnd
                    base=red, rounded corners},
            D/.style = {diamond, draw=#1, fill=#1!50, inner sep=2mm, anchor=center},
       if/.style = {base=teal, align=left,
                    label={[D=teal]north east:}},
            lbl/.style = {inner ysep=2pt, font=\small, text=black!75},
       lb/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=north west]south:#1}},
       ll/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south east]west:#1}},
       lr/.style = {label={[lbl, anchor=south west]east:#1}},
       pc/.style = {% ProCess
                    base=orange},
       io/.style = {base=blue,
                    trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110},
%
every chain label/.style={inner sep=1mm, font=\footnotesize},
off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}          % <== defined interruption of chain
                    ]
% nodes
\node   [be]    {Start};                            % name: A-1
\node   [io]    {Input:\\ f(), a, b, $\varepsilon$};
\node   [pc]    {c=(a+b)/2};
\node   [if,
         ll=True,
         lb=False]  {if:\\ f(a)*f(b)$>$0};          % A-4
\node   [if,
         lb=False,
         lr=True]  {While:\\                        % A-5
                    f(c) $\not=$ 0 \& \\
                    $|$f(b) - f(a)$|$ $> \delta$};
\node   [pc]    {c=(a+b)/2};
\node   [if,
         lb=False,
         ll=True]  {if:\\ f(a)*f(c)\textless 0};    % A-7
\node   [pc]    {a=c};

\node   [io]
                {Output: H, V, T};
\node   [pc]    {Plot:\\ H on T and V on T};
\node   [be]    {Stop};                             % A-11
%% nodes out of chain
\node   [pc, off chain,
         left=of A-7] {b = c};                      % A-12
\node   [io, off chain,
        left=of A-9]       {Output: H, V, T};       % A-13

%%% arrows in main branch
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,2,...,7, 9,10}
\draw[arr]  (A-\i) -- (A-\j);

%%%% arrows on the left
\draw[arr]  (A-4)  -|-[distance=54mm] (A-13.west); % node distance+text width+2*(inner sep)+distance
\draw[arr]  (A-7)  -- (A-12);
\draw[arr]  (A-8.west) -|-[distance=-50mm] ([yshift=2mm] A-5);
\draw[arr]  (A-12) |- ([yshift=-2mm] A-5.west);
\draw[arr]  (A-13) |- (A-10);
%%%% arrows on the right
\draw[arr]  (A-5)   -|-[distance=8mm]  (A-9.east);
\draw[arr]  (A-10)  -|-[distance=12mm] (A-3.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That is very nice. But I have a little question left, for example I want the row to the middle of processes. For Example let say a row gets out from "Plot: H on T and V on T" to the middle(between) of the "Input: f(), a, b, epsilon" and "c=(a+b)/2". So that the row shows to the line between both

Comment: @IHPro, I do not understand your comment. New row in some node?  Or add new node in flowchart? For insert new nodet just insert it below node after which you like that it be, or left/right of node where if it should be parallel to it. For new text row terminate text before it with `\\`  text above it and than write new text line. However the best is ask new question and show, how you try (so far) to extend my MWE  and where you stuck in this. Answer as is, completely (as well the other too) solve your question. So, I think,  it is time that you consider to accept one of them.

Comment: Sorry that my description wasn't clear. I add a picture, maybe that helps to understand my question

Comment: @IHPro, You change the question, but in my comment I suggest you to ask new question where you show, what you try so far. .... BTW, this can be done on similar way ae are draw other arrow on the right side of flowchart, just select appropriate start and end arrow coordinate (i.e. : node name).

Answer (score 1):

As usual, there are many ways

- to declare nodes,
- to place nodes and
- to connect them.

Here are two solutions.

The first one uses the `graphs` library to declare nodes and connect them while the `chains` and the `positioning` library is used to place them.

The second solution uses a `\matrix` to place the nodes on a grid. (Unfortunatly, with `matrix of nodes` the `\\` can't easily be used inside a node. But for this, I'll provide the `\n` shortcut.)
The `graphs` is used here, too, to connect the nodes. It just provides an easier syntax then the `edge` path operation, in my opinion.

In both solutions, the provided name, e.g. `st'0`, `IO'1`, etc. is used to also style the node, everything that comes before the `'` is used for a style, e.g. `style st`, `style IO`, etc. In the `\matrix` solution, this given name is not used with the `name` key but the `alias` key so that the nodes in the matrix still have their `<matrix name>-<row>-<column>` name available. This would allow the `matrix` to be turned into a `tikzcd` diagram. (Though, I believe the overview is lost if we also mix in `\ar` commands into the matrix.)

The `show node names` key can be used to display the name of the main nodes in the upper left corner:

[image: node names shown]

I don't like the diamond shape that much. I'll suggest a `chamfered rectangle` with the `STYLE if=chamfered` option:

[image: chamfered if]

With `STYLE if=labeled` we can have a small diamond in the upper right corner of a normal rectangle instead:

[image: labeled if]

---

As always with these kind of diagrams, I'm using the `ext.paths.ortho` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext).
It provides the path operation `r-rl` which first draws a horizontal line to the right, then a vertical line to the target node and the a horizontal line back to the target.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,      % arrow tips
  shapes.geometric, % diamond, trapezium
  quotes,           % "nodes" on edges
  positioning,      % left=of
  ext.paths.ortho,  % r-rl and r-lr path operations
  shapes.misc,      % chamfered rectangle
  %
  matrix,           % matrix of nodes
  chains,           % start chain, on chain
  graphs,           % \graph
}
\tikzset{
  COMMON/.style={
    /utils/exec=\def\|{\textbar},
    node distance = 7mm and 1cm, row sep=7mm, column sep=1cm,
    style me/.style args={##1'##2}{style ##1/.try},
    style normal/.style={
      draw, minimum width=+3.5cm, minimum height=+1cm, align=center},
    style st/.append style={
      shape=rectangle, style normal, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
    style op/.append style={style st},
    style IO/.style={
      shape=trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
      style normal, align=left,  fill=blue!30},
    style PC/.style={
      shape=rectangle, style normal, fill=orange!30},
    style if/.style={
      shape=diamond, style normal, align=left, fill=green!30, aspect=2},
    rl/.style={to path={r-rl(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    lr around/.style={to path={
      -|([xshift=-1cm]##1.west)|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    ortho/rl distance=1cm, ortho/lr distance=3.5cm,
    vh/.style={to path={|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
    hv/.style={to path={-|(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}},
  },
  STYLE if/.is choice, STYLE if/diamond/.style=,
  STYLE if/chamfered/.style={style if/.append style=chamfered rectangle},
  STYLE if/labeled/.style={style if/.append style={shape=rectangle, label={
    [diamond, draw, fill=white, anchor=center, fill=green!30]north east:}}},
  MATRIX/.style={n/.style args={##1'##2}{alias={##1'##2}, style me={##1'##2}}},
  GRAPHS/.style={
    graphs/every graph/.append style={no placement,
      nodes={style me/.expand once=\tikzgraphnodename}},
    set text/.code=\def\tikzgraphnodetext{##1},
    style st/.append style={set text=Start},
    style op/.append style={set text=Stop}},
  show node names/.style={style me/.append style={
    label={[overlay,node font=\small]north west:##1'##2}}}
}
\begin{document}\ttfamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, COMMON, GRAPHS, STYLE if=labeled]
\graph[/tikz/start chain=down going below] {
  {[nodes={on chain=down}]
  st'0 ->          IO'1 / "Input:\\ f(), a, b, $\varepsilon$"
       ->          PC'1 / "c=(a+b)/2"
       ->          if'1 / "if:\\f(a)*f(b) $>$ 0"
       ->["False"] if'2 / "While:\\f(c) $\not=$ 0 \&\\
                                   \|f(b) - f(a)\| $> \delta$"
       ->["True"]  PC'2 / "c=(a+b)/2"
       ->          if'3 / "if:\\f(a)*f(c) $<$ 0"
       ->["False"] PC'3 / "a=c",
                   IO'2 / "Output:\\H, V, T"
       ->          PC'4 / "Plot:\\H on T and V on T"[align=left]
       ->          op'0,
  },
  if'3 ->["True"]                  PC'5 / "b=c" [left=of if'3]
       ->[vh]                      if'2,
  if'2 ->[rl, "False" near start]  IO'2,
  if'1 ->[hv, "True" above right]
                IO'3 / "Output:\\H, V, T" [left=of PC'5.west|-IO'2]
       ->[vh]                      op'0,
  PC'3 ->[lr around=PC'5]          if'2
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle, COMMON, MATRIX, STYLE if=chamfered]
\newcommand*\n{\node[name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={anchor=center}] {
  & &  |[n=st'0]| Start                               \\
  & & \n[n=IO'1] {Input:\\ f(), a, b, $\varepsilon$}; \\
  & &  |[n=PC'1]| c=(a+b)/2                           \\
  & & \n[n=if'1] {if:\\f(a)*f(b) $>$ 0};                \\
  & & \n[n=if'2] {While:\\f(c) $\not=$ 0 \&\\
                          \|f(b) - f(a)\| $> \delta$}; \\
  & &  |[n=PC'2]| c=(a+b)/2                           \\
  & |[n=PC'5]|   b=c
    & \n[n=if'3] {if:\\f(a)*f(c) $<$ 0};                \\
  & &  |[n=PC'3]| a=c                                 \\
 \n[n=IO'3]      {Output:\\H, V, T};
  & & \n[n=IO'2] {Output:\\H, V, T};                  \\
  & & \n[n=PC'4, align=left] {Plot:\\H on T and V on T}; \\
  & & |[n=op'0]| Stop                                 \\
};
\graph[use existing nodes]{
  st'0 ->          IO'1 
       ->          PC'1 
       ->          if'1 
       ->["False"] if'2 
       ->["True"]  PC'2 
       ->          if'3 
       ->["False"] PC'3 
      -!-          IO'2 
       ->          PC'4 
       ->          op'0,
  if'2 ->[rl, "False" near start]  IO'2,
  if'3 ->["True"]                  PC'5
       ->[vh]                      if'2,
  if'1 ->[hv, "True" above right]  IO'3
       ->[vh]                      op'0,
  PC'3 ->[lr around=PC'5]          if'2
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very interesting answer, especially the very  new (very demanding) package. Please, provide such link for it, that it can be easy accessible (without to have CTAN account). I liked shape for "decison" nodes, ...

Comment: And of course +1 :-)

Comment: @Zarko That was a typo in the url. It should now lead to the normal package page on CTAN (and there's also a link to the repo in case one can't use CTAN). I understand the need for a diamond for a decision node (because it's the language standard) but for long conditions, the diamond shape gets ridicilously large. I don't know what the agreed-upon standard is for that. I'm seeing a lot of small diamonds with what would be in TikZ a `pin` with description text.

Comment: I just tested your code. My MiKtEX load your package "on the fly". At compilation I get error `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ortho/lr distance' ...`. If I force compilation, I get shoed result. BTW, is important order of libraries loading?

Comment: @Zarko I've sent CTAN an update three days ago. It seems like you only have gotton the previous version 0.3 (the key was `udlr/lr distance` then). `ext.paths.ortho` redefines a few TikZ path hooks (for detection of `-|-`, `|-|` and all `r-*` operations) but even another third-party library redefines them the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well, than I need to wait for while ...  Thank you very much for info!

Answer (score 0):

You question is not fully clear to me, but I assume that you are trying to achieve something like this (the arrow does not overlap any nodes and a line break is inserted into the green diamond-shaped node in the middle):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
    startstop/.style={
        rectangle, 
        rounded corners, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered, 
        draw=black, 
        fill=red!30
    },
    io/.style={
        trapezium, 
        trapezium left angle=70, 
        trapezium right angle=110, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=1cm, 
        text centered, 
        draw=black, 
        fill=blue!30
    },
    process/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum width=3cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        text centered,
        draw=black, 
        fill=orange!30
    }, 
    decision/.style={
        diamond, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=1cm, 
        text centered,
        align=center,         % add
        draw=black, 
        fill=green!30,
    },
    arrow/.style={
        thick,
        ->,
        >=stealth
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1.3cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
    \node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input: f(), a, b, $\varepsilon$};
    \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {c=(a+b)/2};
    \node (if1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-1.5cm] {if: f(a)*f(b)$>$0};
    %   \node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
    \node (dec1) [decision, below of=if1, yshift=-4cm] {While: f(c) $\not=$ 0 \& \\ $|$f(b) - f(a)$|$ $> \delta$};
    \node (pro1a) [process, below of=dec1, yshift=-3cm] {c=(a+b)/2};
    \node (dec2) [decision, below of=pro1a, yshift=-1.75cm] {if: f(a)*f(c) $<$ 0};
    \node (pro2) [process, left of=dec2, xshift=-3cm] {b=c};
    \node (pro3) [process, below of=dec2, yshift=-1.5cm] {a=c};
    \node (out1) [io, below of=pro3] {Output: H, V, T};
    \node (out2) [io, left of=out1, xshift=-4.5cm] {Output: H, V, T};
    \node (pro4) [process, below of=out1] {Plot: H on T and V on T};
    \node (stop) [startstop, below of=pro4] {Stop};
    
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
    \draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
    \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (if1);
    \draw [arrow] (if1) -- node {False} (dec1);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node {True} (pro1a);
    \draw [arrow] (pro1a) -- (dec2);
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node {False} (pro3);
    %\draw [arrow] (if1)  -- ++(-5.5,-0) -- ++(-1.5,0) |- node [below right] {True} (out2)
    \draw [arrow] (if1) -| node [above right] {True} ([xshift=-1cm]out2.north);  % replace to coordinate
    \draw [arrow] (pro2) |- (dec1.190);                                          % repplace to coordinate
    \draw [arrow] (pro3)  -- ++(-3.5,-0) -- ++(-2.5,0) |- (dec1.170);            % repplace to coordinate
    \draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node {True} (pro2);
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- ++(2.5,-0) -- ++(3,0) |- node [right] {False} (out1);
    \draw [arrow] (out1) -- (pro4);
    \draw [arrow] ([xshift=-1cm]out2.south) |- (stop);                           % replace from coordinate
    \draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I hope that this is somewhat close to what you want to achieve and at least can help you to get started. I adjusted the `node distance` a bit to make it look less cramped.

Let me add a short explanation on the relevant adjustments:

- Adding the option `align=center` to a node allows you to add line breaks using a double backslash (\) inside the node text.
- You can use the anchors `<node>.north` and `<node>.south` to refer to the top and the bottom of a node. Also, you can add `[xshift=<dim>]` to a coordinate to shift it to the left or right or `[yshift=<dim>]` to shift it up or down. Hence, you can, for example, shift the arrow on the left by replacing the node name `out2` by the shifted coordinate of the relevant anchor using `[xshift=-1cm]out2.north` and `[xshift=-1cm]out2.north` respectively.
- An alternative apporach is to use so called border anchors which are arranged in a counterclockwise manner starting from the right side of the node and are given in degrees. So, the anchor `<node>.90` would typically sit at the same position as `<node>.north`, but you can also use other values than `90`. I used this approach to add a distance between the two arrows that point to the green diamond node in the middle.

Comment: `below of=` (instead of `below=of` from the `positioning` library) shouldn't be used here, I think. The `of=` variants place the nodes in relation to their center where the `=of` variants place them in relation to their border. With that you should be able to lose all the `yshift`s.