# Improve flowchart (aequidistant boxes, endposition/bend of arrows)

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following MWE produces a flowchart I want to improve:

- The arrow leaving to the left should bend upwards after, say 5mm.
- The arrow leaving to the left should end exactly on the half distance of the arrow from `(1)--(2)`
- The arrow leaving the decision to the right should do the same but "zigzag" into `(6)` from the north (means: after going down the arrow should bend left, then down/or enter the box from the east.
- Is it possible to set nodes distances with respect of their "objects dimension"? I want a constant distance between each object no matter how "long" they are.

Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{
    intersections,
    arrows,
    patterns,
    shapes,
    positioning,
    calc,
}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block1}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=white!20, text width=6cm]
\tikzstyle{block2}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw, fill=white!20, text width=6cm]
\tikzstyle{decision}  = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=white!20, text width=2cm]
\tikzstyle{line}      = [draw, ->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]
  % Place nodes
  \node [block1] (1) {%
    \textbf{Initialisation}\\%
    $\vec{P} \left[ 1 \right]$
    };
  \node [block1, below of=1,]  (2)  {%
    \textbf{Fitness evaluation} \\ %
    $\vec{x}^{i} = \text{d}(\Theta^{i})$,\\ %
    $f^{i}=f{\vec{x}^{i}}$};
    \node [decision, below of=2,]  (3)  {%
      \textbf{Stop crit. met?}};
  \node [block1, below of=3,]  (4)  {%
    \textbf{Selection}};
    \node [block2, below of=4,]  (5)  {%
    \centerline{\textbf{Mating}} \\
    \textbullet~Chromosome crossover \\
    \textbullet~Segregation\\
    \textbullet~Mutation};
  \node [block1, below of=5,]  (6)  {%
  \textbf{Select solution}\\
      $i = \text{argmax}(f^{i})$,\\
      $\vec{x}^{\ast} = \vec{x}^{i}$};

      % % Draw edges
  \path [line] (1) -- node [] {$\vec{P}[k]$}(2);
  \path [line] (2) -- (3);
  \path [line] (3) -- node [] {No}(4);
  \path [line] (3.east) |- node [above] {Yes}(6);
  \path [line] (4) -- node [] {}(5);
  \path [line] (5.west) |- node [] {$\vec{P}[k+1]=\vec{C}[k]$}(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
block1/.style   ={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=white!20, text width=6cm},
block2/.style   ={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw, fill=white!20, text width=6cm},
decision/.style ={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=white!20, text width=2cm},
line/.style     ={-Stealth},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, auto]
\node[block1] (1) {\textbf{Initialisation}\\$\vec{P} \left[ 1 \right]$};
\node[block1, below of=1] (2) {\textbf{Fitness evaluation}\\$\vec{x}^{i}=\text{d}(\Theta^{i})$,\\$f^{i}=f{\vec{x}^{i}}$};
\node[decision, below of=2] (3) {\textbf{Stop crit. met?}};
\node[block1, below of=3] (4) {\textbf{Selection}};
\node[block2, below of=4] (5) {\centerline{\textbf{Mating}}\\\textbullet~Chromosome crossover\\\textbullet~Segregation\\\textbullet~Mutation};
\node[block1, below of=5] (6) {\textbf{Select solution}\\$i=\text{argmax}(f^{i})$,\\$\vec{x}^{\ast}=\vec{x}^{i}$};

\draw[line] (1) --node{$\vec{P}[k]$} (2);
\draw[line] (2) -- (3);
\draw[line] (3) --node{No} (4);
\draw[line] (3.east) --node[above]{Yes} +(2.5,0) |- ($ (5.south)!0.5!(6.north) $) --(6.north);
\draw[line] (4) -- (5);
\draw[line] (5.west) -- +(-0.5,0) |-node[pos=0.75]{$\vec{P}[k+1]=\vec{C}[k]$} ($ (1.south)!0.5!(2.north) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Decision tree]

Answer (score 2):

One add (prrovvisory) to the very pro Hpekristiansen's answer to better understand the same.
Add two lines of code just after `\begin{tikzpicture}`:

```
\draw[gray!15] (-4,-16) grid (4,2);
\foreach \x/\t in {0/(1),-3/(2),-6/(3),-9/(4),-12/(5),-15/(6)} \node at (-4.2,\x) {\small $\t$};
```

You have this output that show well all the block of picture:

[image]

where I added also some cosmetic colors to styles definitions of `block1`, `block2` and `decision`.
After full understing of all the Hpekristiansen's code You can delete or comment my two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw your flowchart using `chains` package and its `join` macro:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{{arg\,max}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                quotes,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 8mm,
    start chain = A going below,
    %
     arr/.style = {-Stealth},
    base/.style = {draw,
                   text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center,
                   font=\bfseries},
     box/.style = {base, rounded corners},
decision/.style = {diamond, base, aspect=1.5, inner sep=-5pt},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=left, font=\small},
every join/.style = {arr}
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A}]
\node[box]  {Initialisation\\
             $\vec{P}[1]$};
\coordinate (aux);
\node[box, join]  {Fitness evaluation\\[1ex]
             $\begin{aligned}
             \vec{x}^{i} & = \text{d}(\Theta^{i}),\\
                   f^{i} & = f{\vec{x}^{i}}
             \end{aligned}$};
\node[decision, join] {Stop\\ crit. met?};
\node[box, join]  {Selection};
\node[box, join]  {Mating\normalfont
                \begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=*]
             \item  Chromosome crossover
             \item  Segregation
             \item  Mutation
                \end{itemize}};
\node[box,
         ]  {Select solution\\[1ex]
            $\begin{aligned}
                         i & = \argmax(f^{i})\\
            \vec{x}^{\ast} & = \vec{x}^{i}
            \end{aligned}$};
    \end{scope}
\draw[arr]   (A-1) to ["{$\vec{P}[k]$}"] (A-3) to ["No"] (A-4);
\draw[arr] (A-4.east) to ["Yes"] ++ (8mm,0) |- ($(A-6.south)!0.5!(A-7.north) $) -- (A-7.north);
\draw[arr] (A-6.west) -- ++(-8mm,0) |- (aux) node[near end,above] {$\vec{P}[k+1]=\vec{C}[k]\quad$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, flowcharts can be drawn on different ways. For example how are drawn in answers on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661461/flowchart-with-overlapping-of-the-rows) question.